# ScrollView not showing Horizontal Scroll Indicator iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to show a horizontal scroll view indicator for my scrollView.I am able to show content inside it but, no success with showing indicator yet.I have already tried setting the `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` to YES , both in code as well as in StoryBoard.What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scrollView.delegate =self;
int x =5;
int y=10;
int width = 50;
int height = 50;
int buffer =10;
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    UIButton *imgButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    imgButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [imgButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imgButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imgButton];
    x= width+buffer;
}

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 1)];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =YES;
}
```

Scroll view frame is : X-160 , Y -232 , Width - 273 , Height - 114

With few changes , here is how it looks, but still no horizontal indicator

[image]

Comment: what is your scroll view frame?

Comment: Have mentioned the frame too

Comment: Your content height is 1.... i imagine the horizontal scroller is larger than 1 pixel high so it can't display ?